# Exception in Application start method while launching application that uses fxml file

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I'm very new to javafx and i never used an fxml file

I already tried searching a solution here but i haven't found anything that solves my case.

Possibly useful info:

File name is correct, the fxml file is located in the same package as the application.

When trying to launch my javafx application i get the following error:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$156(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2434)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
    at GUIs.DebuggingGUI.start(DebuggingGUI.java:39)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$163(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$176(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$174(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$175(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$149(WinApplication.java:191)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application GUIs.DebuggingGUI
```

The code for the application is:

```
package GUIs;

import ADTs.Adress;
import Observer.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import Controller.*;
import sun.security.ssl.Debug;

//ToDo with scene builder
public class DebuggingGUI extends Application{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        launch(args);

    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        try {
            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("DebuggingView.fxml"));
            Parent root = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
            primaryStage.setTitle("Debugging environment for Apollo");
            primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1800, 800));
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

While this is the fxml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>


<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <top>
      <HBox prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </top>
   <center>
      <ImageView fx:id="MainView" fitHeight="150.0" fitWidth="200.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </center>
   <left>
      <VBox prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <Button fx:id="StepButton" alignment="CENTER" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#StepVM" text="Step" />
         </children>
      </VBox>
   </left>
</BorderPane>
```

Comment: Either the filename or the path to the FXML file **is** incorrect. There are a **lot** of answers to this exact same question already on StackOverflow.

Comment: Another possibility is the resource not being added to the classpath at runtime...

Comment: @Zephyr the filename is correct and the answers i found didn't solve my problem unfortunately

Comment: @fabian how would i solve that?

Comment: Depends on how you're building your project. First, check that the resources are copied to the build location. If they aren't, and you're using your IDE to build, lookup how to include resource files for your specific IDE; if you're using a build tool lookup how to include resources for your build tool. Note that build tools like Maven or Gradle expect resources to be under `<project-dir>/src/main/resources` by default.